# C言語での乱数生成で常に同じ値となってしまうケースがある

Tags: xcode, c, random

以下のコードで `num` は0~6になる思うのですが、すべて4になってしまいます。
`num=rand()%7` の7を他の数字でやると0〜その数字の間の数となります。
7の時のみこのようになってしまうのですがなぜでしょうか？

環境は MacBook Pro、xcode Version 6.1です。

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i,num;

    srand(time(NULL));
    num=rand()%7;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\n",num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ４から始まるという意味なら、時間をおいて実行してみて下さい。

Answer (score 17):

forループの中で `num` の値は変更されていませんから、最初に決まった値を毎回表示することになります。必要であればforループの中で`num`の値を再設定してください。

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    num=rand()%7;
    printf("%d\n",num);
}
```

---

quesera2さんがXcodeにおけるrandの実装のリンクを張られています。

```
static int
do_rand(unsigned long *ctx)
{
#ifdef  USE_WEAK_SEEDING
/*
 * Historic implementation compatibility.
 * The random sequences do not vary much with the seed,
 * even with overflowing.
 */
    return ((*ctx = *ctx * 1103515245 + 12345) % ((u_long)RAND_MAX + 1));
#else   /* !USE_WEAK_SEEDING */
/*
 * Compute x = (7^5 * x) mod (2^31 - 1)
 * wihout overflowing 31 bits:
 *      (2^31 - 1) = 127773 * (7^5) + 2836
 * From "Random number generators: good ones are hard to find",
 * Park and Miller, Communications of the ACM, vol. 31, no. 10,
 * October 1988, p. 1195.
 */
    long hi, lo, x;

    /* Can't be initialized with 0, so use another value. */
    if (*ctx == 0)
        *ctx = 123459876;
    hi = *ctx / 127773;
    lo = *ctx % 127773;
    x = 16807 * lo - 2836 * hi;
    if (x < 0)
        x += 0x7fffffff;
    return ((*ctx = x) % ((u_long)RAND_MAX + 1));
#endif  /* !USE_WEAK_SEEDING */
}
```

となっています。`srand(time(NULL));`直後の`rand()%7`の値に限定すると、
変数`hi`は`127773`で除算しているので127773秒ごとにしか変化しません。変数`lo`は`7^5`を乗じているので7の倍数です。つまり、127773秒（およそ35.5時間）周期でしか7の剰余の値は変化しません。

Answer (score 8):

`num=rand()%7;`を`for`文に移動すれば、同じ数値が返ってくることはなくなります。

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i,num;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // キャストしないと警告文が出ると思いますが？

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){  
        num=rand()%7;
        printf("%d\n",num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

しかし、これでもじつはまだ問題が残ってしまいます。というのは、なんどビルドして実行しても初回の値がかならず4になるという現象が現れます。乱数を使用する目的からすれば、都合が悪い現象です。
これはXcodeがインストールする、**CLang+LLVMが内蔵する擬似乱数発生のアルゴリズム**に欠陥があるからといえると思います。
乱数表の冒頭は捨てて、途中を採用すれば、より良い結果が得られると思います。

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i,num;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    // 乱数表の冒頭10個は捨てる。
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        rand();
    };

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        num=rand()%7;
        printf("%d\n",num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

擬似乱数発生のアルゴリズムに完璧なものはないと言われています。用途に応じて、使い分けるか、上のような工夫が必要でしょう。
Mac、iOS上のプログラムなら、`arc4random()`、`arc4random_uiiform()`という、Free BSD由来の関数が使え、C言語の`rand()`関数より高い品質の乱数表を得られるといいます。

Comment: このコードで違う数値が出る処理系があったらお目にかかりたいのですが・・・もしかしてスルー力のテストだったりするのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答を補筆いたしました。質問者さんとの間だけ、コミュニケーションがとれていればいいと思っていましたが、そうはいかないと痛感いたしました。おわびいたします。

Comment: いくら貧弱な乱数アルゴリズムであっても `srand(time(NULL));` にて乱数のシードを変更しているため、プログラムを実行する度にnumの値は変わると思うのですが、Xcode環境では異なるのでしょうか？

Comment: @Harawo printf のループ内で num を更新していないので違う数値になるはずが無いと言いたいのですが・・・

Comment: @sayuri 変わっているはずですけど、7の剰余をとると4になるんですね。7以外の剰余でも、たとえば0、1、2、3、0、1、2、3……と循環するとか、明らかな規則性が表れます。（Xcodeでは、ですけど）

Comment: 内容を検討し、変更と補筆をいたしました。

Comment: さらに調べましたが、どうもMac+Xcode特有の問題のようです。

Comment: 検証ありがとうございます。オイラんとこでの検証では、とりあえず VC++2005, cygwin の gcc, HPUX11.11 の srand は問題なかったです。貴重な情報なのにマイナスモデがもったいないなあ。

Comment: @Harawo なるほど % 2 すると 0 / 1 を交互に繰り返すのと同じようなもので、乱数の精度が低いわけですね。

Comment: Xcode6.4(6E35b)および7βでは仰られているような事象は発生せず、また[公開されている実装](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583/stdlib/FreeBSD/rand.c)を読んでも「必ず初回の乱数値が4になる」という致命的欠陥の証左は見当たりませんでした。プラスモデ入れた方はご自身で再検証されたのでしょうか？

Comment: @quesera2 Macがなければ、「再検証」はできないと思います。この件は[Qiita](http://qiita.com/susanuwo/items/816d153f0b3dcafc912e)に投稿しました。Replyはそちらにお願いします。

Comment: @Harawo 第一に、OSX/iOSの利用しているrand()がどういう実装なのかソースコードを提示しました。コードから実装の妥当性を検証することが可能なのは、プログラマでしたらご存知かと思います。古典的な線形合同法アルゴリズムですが、入力エントロピーが十分であれば擬似乱数としては特段欠陥と騒ぐような実装ではありません。第二に、Clangはコンパイラですし、LLVMはコンパイラ基盤であり、擬似乱数のアルゴリズムは内臓していません。SOをナレッジ集積の場と考えたとき、そのような見当外れな指摘に対する反論を残しておくのは有意義だと思いますので、Qiitaにリプライをお願いされても聞く道理はないと考えます。