# vectorの要素をrandom_shuffleを使ってシャッフルしたいが、srand(time(0))とシードの設定をしてもシャッフルが毎回同じになってしまう

Tags: c++

タイトルの通り、vectorの要素をシャッフルしたいのですが毎回同じになってしまい困っています。

どなたか間違いのご指摘お願いできないでしょうかm(_ _)m

**-----動作環境-----**

**g++ --version**

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-  dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/De
veloper/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

**OS info**

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.3
BuildVersion:   16D32
```

**コンパイル方法**

```
g++ test.cpp
```

**test.cppの中身**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> // time
#include <cstdlib> // rand
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; ++i) v.push_back(i);

    cout << "vector before shuffling : ";

    vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
    for(iter=v.begin(); iter!=v.end(); ++iter) cout << *iter << ' ';

    cout << endl << endl;

    // shuffle vector
    srand(time(0));
    random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

    cout << "vector after shuffling : ";
    for(iter=v.begin(); iter!=v.end(); ++iter) cout << *iter << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` が抜けている様ですが…参考までに、`Ubuntu Linux 17.04/GNU C++ 7.0.1` ではシャッフルされます。

Comment: ご指摘の通り#include <algorithm>が抜けていたので追加しましたm(_ _)m しかしrandom_shuffleが同じシャッフルをしてしまう問題が解決できないので引き続き解決策を模索中です。

Comment: ブラウザ上でC++を実行できるサービスを使って[実行してみた結果です](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y9APrVThfALSxIQV)。この環境では毎回シャッフルできているようです。`gcc --version`の結果や、コンパイルしたときのコマンドの内容、実行しているOS環境などを追記願えませんでしょうか？ 自分の質問は質問の下の「編集」から自由に編集できます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございますm(_ _)m 動作環境を追加しました。実行結果ありがとうございます、そちらでは実際にシャッフルができているのでむしろコンパイラ等の問題なのでしょうか?

Comment: ちなみに、`random_shuffle` は C++14 で非推奨となっています。[random_shuffle](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle.html) の「非推奨の詳細」の部分。

Comment: コメントありがとうございますm(_ _)m c++14では非推奨なのですねー。コンパイルの方法をg++ -std=c++11 test.cpp に変更したのですが以前としてシャッフルが同じになってしまうので別の方法を模索することにします。

Comment: xcode の `srand` の実装が末端プログラマに対して直観的でないという話が既に出てますね http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12003/ この辺の関連かも

Comment: コメント&リンクありがとうございますm(_ _)m srandの実装の問題ということで納得しましたので、srandを使用しないコードに書き換えることに致しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

774RRさんがすでにコメントされていますが、Mac OSの実装では`srand(time(0))`で初期化すると短期的には最初の`rand()`の結果が毎秒`16807`ずつ増加するという規則性があります。この仕様により固定的な動作をしてしまう場合があります。詳細は[こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/12005/4236)。