# データ構造とアルゴリズムは実務ではどんなシーンで役立つのか？

Tags: アルゴリズム, データ構造

現在スタック、キュー、ツリー、ソートなどを始めとしたデータ構造とアルゴリズムの勉強をしています。これはエンジニアの基礎的なスキルだから(と世間様が言ってる)という理由が私のモチベーションです。

ですがここで質問です。

#### 質問

**これらが重要と認識されてる方は、これまでご自身の開発でどのようなシーンで使ってきたか教えてもらいたいです。もしできれば、実際の現場レベルでの活用事例を紹介したWebサイトの紹介もお願いしたいです**

というのも、RailsやDjangoやZend FrameworkなどによるWebアプリケーションやiOSアプリ、機械学習などの領域でこれらを使ったことがあるというエンジニアが周りにいないです。私も使った記憶がありません。でもなんで世間様はこんなにもデータ構造とアルゴリズムを重視されてるのでしょうか。特にアメリカ西海岸のIT企業などで。

コーディング面接で必要であったり、Googleのような超巨大なサービスではフルに活用しないとパフォーマンス、サーバーのコストなどに雲泥の差が出てくるんだろうなとは思っています。

ですが、世の中の殆どのSEのうち、このような巨大なサービスでパフォーマンスをチューニングしてる人は一握りだけでしょう。

彼ら以外でもデータ構造やアルゴリズムをうまく活用している人たちはいるかもしれませんが、どのように用いてるのか全く検討もつきません。「XXXのような仕様のアプリケーションでフレームワークにはXXXを用いており、具体的にこういう処理で必要になる」くらいの事例をものすごく知りたいです。

例えばソートは組み込み関数で行えるので、どのソートアルゴリズムを使うのかなんて考えないです。ツリー構造でのトラバーサルなどそもそもデータをツリー構造にする時点で全然イメージがわかないうえ、post order トラバーサルとかlevel order トラバーサルやAVL木なんて実務でいつ使うんでしょうか。RDBのインデックスで使ってるとかそういうのは知ってますが、そんな低レイヤーをいじるのは一握りの人だけですよね。

長々と書きましたが、データ構造やアルゴリズムが必要とされるのはかなり一握りの人たちだけでほとんどのSEには必要のないこと、知らなくても業務はこなせるのになんでこんなにデータ構造やアルゴリズムがもてはやされてるのでしょうか、ということが気になっています。

#### 追記

実際にデータ構造やアルゴリズムの勉強をしていると、そんなのなんの役に立つの？などと聞かれることが多々あります。上長に説明しても、そんなのGAFAに入るために必要なだけでしょとか失笑されます。

Comment: 例えば、WEBページは、HTMLというマークアップ言語で書かれています。それは、HTMLの文法に従ったデータ構造を持つデータです。HTMLの文法を知らずして、WEBページは作れません。
「WebアプリケーションでHTMLのデータ構造を使ったことがあるというエンジニアが周りにいない」という環境は稀有だと思います。

Comment: すみません、それが今回の質問とどのように関係しているのでしょうか

Comment: ブラウザでのレンダリングで必要とかそういう話ですかね

Comment: 「データ構造が実務で使われているのか、役立つか」という質問に対する一つの例ではないでしょうか。HTMLがここで言うデータ構造にあたるかは議論の余地がありますが

Comment: 例えば、よくあるのはランキングの実装をどうするかだと思います。こいつは割と、気をぬくとすぐに遅くなるので、じゃあ早くするにしてもどうやって実現する？を考えると、アルゴリズムとデータ構造的な思考が必要になるかと思います。

Comment: 個人的には、こういう類いの質問はStakoverflowではなく[Quora](https://jp.quora.com/topic/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0)の方が向いているのではないかと考えます。

Comment: 「もてはやされてる/重視されてる」というのは、ご自身の経験に基づくものですか？それとも何かの記事等で見聞きした情報でしょうか？ / ググると該当するような[翻訳記事の一つ](https://postd.cc/50-data-structure-and-algorithms-interview-questions-for-programmers/)ヒットしますが、それらの知識を重視しているというよりは「技術者の技量を推し量る」質問に過ぎないような気がしますし、[はてブでの反応](http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/s/postd.cc/50-data-structure-and-algorithms-interview-questions-for-programmers/)は同意よりも懐疑的な意見の方が多いです (元の記事は海外での話ですから)。

Comment: @AkiyamaNao さん、ご質問ありがとうございます。こちらのご質問をどう扱うべきかがメタというサイトで議論されていますので、お時間ある際にご確認いただければ幸いです。お手数おかけしてすいません<(\_ \_)> https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2997/19110

Answer (score 9, accepted):

巨大なシステムでは重要≒普通のシステムでは知らなくてよい、とお考えのようですがとんでもない話です。資源の少ないマイコンでは RAM も貴重 ROM も貴重、電池も貴重で、最適なアルゴリズムやデータ構造を使わないと１つ１つの処理に余計な時間がかかります。電池機器（まあ端的にはスマホっすけど）では無駄な処理は一切許されません。ほぼ同じような処理をして A 社のスマホは電池が１０時間保つけど B 社のスマホは２０時間保つ、とかなればお客様は B 社に流れてしまいます。この辺の事情はPCでも同じことですよ。

データ構造、アルゴリズムの

- 詳しい実装までは知らなくてもよい（たいていは既にライブラリ化されているので、ありがたく使わせていただくだけで良い）のですが
- 本質的に何がどう違ってどういうメリット・デメリットがあるか、は知っておかないと選択の余地がありません

他にも例えばカルドセプトというゲームでサイコロの出目がバグっている事件なんてのがありましたが、これも「疑似乱数」というアルゴリズムを正しく理解せずに使ってしまったがゆえに発生したものと推定されています。こんなバグを出してしまったメーカーの技術力は大いに疑われる、つまり市場の信頼を失ってしまいます。

知っていればもてはやされる、レベルの話ではなくて
知らないと失笑される、と考えてください。

Comment: なるほど、マイコンですか、それは必要そうですね。組み込みエンジニアの方もおっしゃっていました。疑似乱数のアルゴリズムについては、その時に調べておけばよかったんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: 実際自分も乱数を使う時に、ちょっと調べてメルセンヌツイスターとか使いましたけどね

Comment: その「ちょっと調べる」ができる人ならカルドセプト出目事件のような恥ずかしいバグは出さないんですよ。

Comment: @AkiyamaNao あくまで上記は例でしょう。知識として事前に知らない人が「さぁ組みましょう」となった時に出来るとは思いません。きっとその時は"動くように組む”のであって、主観的に動作していると判断すればリリースしてしまうでしょう。そしてアルゴリズムを知らない人が最適化できているかどうかも分からない。774RRさんの例も"擬似乱数"が組んだ人から見て「動いているように見えた」からリリースされて、指摘されてから調べて理解し直しますとなったら「最初からこうしておけばよかった」となるかと思います。コンテンツを設置するサーバの費用についてもそうです。十分に最適化されていないデータ構造やアルゴリズムで処理コストを浪費すると後から「維持費高いからシステム最適化してスケールダウンしてよ」となった時に泣くことになります。そして一度リリースし稼動してしまったらデータ構造など根底にあるものを直すのは大変です。

Comment: 疑似乱数について、[特定条件下で常に同じ値になる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/12005/4236)という質問があったりしました。