# １秒以内に実行をくりかえすと同じシード値になる問題を解決したい

Tags: c, random

C言語で乱数を生成するプログラムをコーディングしているのですが、シード値を時間から指定しているため、１秒以内にプログラムを実行すると、同じシード値となり、同じ乱数が生成されてしまいます。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // 1秒以内に実行すると同じシード値になってしまいます

    // 最小値:0 取得個数:10個
    printf("%d\n", 0 + rand() % 10);

    return 0;
}
```

プログラムを１秒以内に何度も実行するので、１秒以内に実行されても異なるシード値になるようにしたいのですが、なにかいい方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept された後ではありますが

`srand()` に渡す値が大差ないときには `rand()` の初回呼出しが返す値を下手な加工して使うと乱数にならない例が既に知られています。
[c言語での乱数生成](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12003)
`time(NULL)` に `getpid()` の結果を**加える**程度だと上記例のような環境だと明らかにまずいです。また `pid_t` の取る値の範囲が狭い処理系 (FreeBSD や HPUX) では**XOR**してもたいした違いにならないのでやはりあまりよろしくないです。というわけで `srand(time(NULL))` はあまり良いプラクティスではありません。避けるべきでしょう。

ではどうすれば良いかは処理系によって異なります。とりあえず

- `srand()` 直後の `rand()` は採用しない（数回~数十回読み捨てる)
- もっとましな乱数種として `/dev/random` 乱数デバイスを使う (存在するなら)
- もっとましな乱数列（と種）に乗り換える (MT とか)

あたりが推奨でしょうか。

Comment: @失われた時を求めて 元質問文からは読み取れなかったのですが、品質の良い乱数を求めていたのでしょうか？ 乱数のseedを変えたいとしか問われていなかったように思います。品質の良い乱数であろうとseedが同じであれば同じ乱数値になりますし、話題がそれているような気がします。

Answer (score 1):

プラットフォームがわかりませんが、[`getpid`](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) とかをXORしてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

英語版での関連しそうな投稿から、いくつか使えそうなものを紹介しておきます。

sayuri さんが回答している通り、`getpid` と組み合わせる方法。

[srand(time(NULL)) doesn't change seed value quick enough - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799756)

> ```c
> srand( (unsigned) time(NULL) * getpid());
> ```

もしくは時間の精度をマイクロ秒まであげる方法などがあるようです。

[srand() — why call it only once? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343909)

> ```c
> struct timeval t1;
> gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
> srand(t1.tv_usec * t1.tv_sec);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

乱数のシード値に、現在時刻のミリ秒を使ったらいいのでは無いでしょうか？